# Error with JS inheritance and Sprites

Tags: javascript, easeljs

So I'm trying to learn javascript and easeljs together to make a TD game. I can have worked out how to extend the sprite class from tutorials to make each game object separately. What am I trying to do though is make a base class that is a `Sprite` and then each object such as `Tower` , `Enemy` will inherit from it.

**Entity.js**

```
function Entity(name, img, x_end) {
   this.initialize(name,img,x_end); <- throws Error 
}

Entity.prototype = new createjs.Sprite();
Entity.prototype.Sprite_initialize = this.initialize; //unique to avoid overiding base class

Entity.prototype.initialize = function (name, img, x_end) {
    var localSpriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
        images: [img], //image to use
        frames: {width: 32, height: 32},
        animations: {
            walk: [0, 0, "walk", 4],
        }
    });

    this.Sprite_initialize(localSpriteSheet);
    this.x_end = x_end;

    // start playing the first sequence:
    this.gotoAndPlay("walk");     //animate

    // starting directly at the first frame of the walk_h sequence
    this.currentFrame = 0;
};
```

**Tower.js**

```
function Tower(TowerName, imgTower, x_end) {

    Entity.call(this,arguments);
}

//Inherit Entity
Tower.prototype = new Entity();

// correct the constructor pointer because it points to Person
Tower.prototype.constructor = Tower;
```

**Main.js**

```
var Towers = new Array();
Towers[0] = new Tower("TowerA", "src/images/arrowtower_thumb2.png", canvas.width)
```

**Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #< Tower > has no method 'initialize'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace :

```
Entity.prototype.Sprite_initialize = this.initialize;
```

with :

```
Entity.prototype.Sprite_initialize = Entity.prototype.initialize;
```

and add a "initialize" method in Tower.js

```
Tower.prototype.Tower_initialize = Tower.prototype.initialize; 
Tower.prototype.initialize = function () {
   ...
}
```